# Closing the merge request using gitlab api?

Tags: curl, gitlab, gitlab-ci, put, gitlab-api

I am trying to close a merge request using gitlab's update merge request api ([update mr](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/merge_requests.html#update-mr))  but its not working

I am trying this

```
curl --request PUT --header "PRIVATE-TOKEN: <your_access_token>" "https://gitlab.example.com/api/v4/projects/4/merge_requests/85?state=closed"
```

but this is not working, am I missing something?

Comment: What kind of error do you get? What is not working? Is the MR still open after the API? We need a bit more details to avoid that we guess.

Answer (score 1):

Given below is the correct way to close a merge request using GitLab API

```
curl --request PUT --header "PRIVATE-TOKEN: <your_access_token>" "https://gitlab.example.com/api/v4/projects/4/merge_requests/85?state_event=close"
```